# Understanding switch/case usage in javascript with floats

Tags: javascript, google-maps, switch-statement

I wrote this code but had an issue that I can't figure out:

I have a list that contains 6 floats but the program does not stop at `case=6` so an error appears

```
@model IList<float>
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Lay2.cshtml";
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");}
<body  onload="initialize(@Model.Count.ToString(culture)">
  <table style="width: 100%; height: 70%">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(a) {

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[0].ToString(culture), @Model[1].ToString(culture));
        var nextpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture));
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[0].ToString(culture), @Model[1].ToString(culture)),
        new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),

        ];
        var flightmarker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[0].ToString(culture), @Model[1].ToString(culture)),
            map: map,
            title: " denden"
        });
        var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
            map: map,
            title: " denden"
        });

        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: flightPlanCoordinates,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        flightPath.setMap(map);
        switch (a) {
        case 6:
            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[4].ToString(culture), @Model[5].ToString(culture)),

            ];
            var flightmarker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[4].ToString(culture), @Model[5].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });

            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
            alert(a);
            break;
        case 8:
            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[4].ToString(culture), @Model[5].ToString(culture)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[6].ToString(culture), @Model[7].ToString(culture))];
            var flightmarker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[4].ToString(culture), @Model[5].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[6].ToString(culture), @Model[7].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
            break;
            alert(a);
        case 10:
            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[4].ToString(culture), @Model[5].ToString(culture)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[6].ToString(culture), @Model[7].ToString(culture)),
            new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[8].ToString(culture), @Model[9].ToString(culture))];
            var flightmarker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[2].ToString(culture), @Model[3].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[4].ToString(culture), @Model[5].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[6].ToString(culture), @Model[7].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightmarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[8].ToString(culture), @Model[9].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden"
            });
            var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
            break;

        }

    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: i have in the liste 6  floats but in function initialize it didn't stop when case:6 it show the error ("Index was out of range. It must not be negative and must be less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index")

Comment: I weep at this question. Why not take a second or two to read the FAQ? It would take considerably more effort to answer this question than you put into asking it. That's not very reasonable by me. -1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the whole problem, You're missing a closing parens on your body tag:

```
<body  onload="initialize(@Model.Count.ToString(culture))">  
// missing the second parens after culture.
```

Comment: It seems to be running in his page just fine tho, since he's having javascript issues?

Comment: the error was exactly " conditional compilation is turned off" so the program can't stop in any cases.what is the solution?